# Tagify with Rails 7 combining JSON tags after submit

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, tagify

I'm using `@yairEO/tagify` on my Rails 7 app. I have it almost working. It will save to the database as valid JSON. If I submit the form using tagify with 3 tags, for example `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`, after I go back to the form to edit, tagify shows these 3 separate tags combined into one single tag.

From the database:

```
[
  {
    "value":"tag1"
  },
  {
    "value":"tag2"
  },
  {
    "value":"tag3"
  }
]
```

From irb `recipe.tags`:

```
[
  {
    "value"=>"tag1"
  },
  {
    "value"=>"tag2"
  },
  {
    "value"=>"tag3"
  }
]
```

Before submitting:
[image: before]

After submitting:
[image: after]

Things quickly get out of control when adding to the bad response. Before submitting:
[image]

After submitting:
[image]

`application.js`

```
import Tagify from "@yaireo/tagify"

document.addEventListener('turbo:load', (event) => {
  new Tagify(document.querySelector('#recipe_tags'));
});
```

`recipes_controller.rb`

```
def update
  @recipe.update(tags: JSON.parse(params[:recipe][:tags]))

  if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

```
def recipe_params
  params[:recipe][:tags] = JSON.parse(params[:recipe][:tags])
  params.require(:recipe).permit(
    :title, :subtitle, :tags
  )
end
```

`edit.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <%= form.label :tags %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :tags %>
  <% recipe.errors.full_messages_for(:tags).each do |message| %>
    <div><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`schema.rb`

```
  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "subtitle"
    t.jsonb "tags", default: {}, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_recipes_on_user_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Rails was sending back a Hash, but the form wanted JSON.

To fix this, I converted the data brought into the form to json:

```ruby
<%= form.label tags %>
<%= form.text_field(tags, value: recipe[tags].to_json) %>
```

Also, to DRY this up, I went ahead and removed these from the `recipes_controller.rb`:

`@recipe.update(tags: JSON.parse(params[:recipe][:tags]))`

and

`params[:recipe][:tags] = JSON.parse(params[:recipe][:tags])`

Then added this to the recipe model:

```
protected

def convert_to_json
  self.tags = JSON.parse(tags) unless tags.empty?
end
```

but we'd need to make sure it's valid JSON before converting, otherwise we end up with the same mess we had in the first place:

```
private

def valid_json?(value)
  result = JSON.parse(value)

  result.is_a?(Hash) || result.is_a?(Array)
rescue JSON::ParserError, TypeError
  false
end
```

then `convert_to_json` becomes `... unless tags.empty? || !valid_json?(tags)`

Seems to be working properly now! If anyone has any tips on how to make this even cleaner/faster/better, let us know. Thanks